# input type text & textarea using htmlentities

Tags: php, html

I have text fetch from db and output inside of input type text & textarea for user to edit their text, my questiong is do I still need use htmlentities?

seems like the code will not run in input type text & textarea

ex.

```
$data="<h1>efijfie</h1>";

<textarea><?PHP echo $data;?></textarea>
```

Comment: You need to post the relevant parts of your code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is yes you need to sanitize data displayed on the web that originates from database data that was input by your users. Here is some more high level information: http://diovo.com/2008/09/sanitizing-user-data-how-and-where-to-do-it/. But a good rule of thumb is to never trust data at any point that is provided by users. Never Ever. Ever.